# Get total product purchased count with specific product attributes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a custom report using WooCommerce and it is working, but it is using a ton of resources, and it needs to be much larger and will time out if I increase its size. I am certain there is a better way to do this.

I am running muliple queries to see how many products of specific colors and sizes have been ordered. Currently, these are separate queries and not efficient.  Here is my code:

This is the function that gets the quantity ordered:

```
function get_order_by_product_id($product_id, $product_color, $product_size) {
    $args = array ( 
            'limit' => '-1',
            'status' => 'processing',
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
    if($orders) :
        $total = 0;
        foreach( $orders as $order) :
            $order_id = $order->get_id();
            $single_order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

            foreach ($single_order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) :
                $product = $item_data->get_product();
                $productID = $single_order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_product_id', true);
                $product_name = $product->get_name();
                $color = $single_order->get_item_meta($item_id, 'pa_colors', true);
                $size = $single_order->get_item_meta($item_id, 'pa_sizes', true);
                $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity();

                if($productID == $product_id && $color == $product_color && $size == $product_size ) :
                    $total += $item_quantity;
                endif;

            endforeach;
        endforeach;
        echo $total;
    endif;
}
```

This is a call to the function:

```
get_order_by_product_id(47652, 'black', 'xs');
```

Currently, in order to make this work, I am calling the function over and over again for each product id, color and size. As I said, it works, but is a resource hog.

Any ideas for increasing efficiency would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could likely write a single SQL query to fetch the information you require, I suggest you jump into a MySQL client (HeidiSQL, MySQL Workbench) and have a play around. Without seeing your database structure there is not enough information here to help you.

Comment: You mean rather than using the built in WooCommerce queries, just do a SQL query instead?

Comment: Yes, you are looking to optimize multiple complex queries, the only way to do that is to bypass the abstraction and go straight for a optimized query, leveraging the database to do what it was designed to do. Not only is your code slow due to the looping, it is asking the database to return data over and over again, increasing network load, MySQL parser load, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a simple lighter SQL query with the following function:

```
/*
 * @param (int)    $product_id 
 * @param (string) $colors     slug term for "pa_colors" product attribute
 * @param (string) $sizes      slug term for "pa_sizes"  product attribute
 * @param (string) $status     Optional: Order status ("processing" by default)
**/
function get_ordered_product_count( $product_id, $colors, $sizes, $status='processing' ){
    return $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(woim.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim1 ON woi.order_item_id = woim1.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim2 ON woi.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim3 ON woi.order_item_id = woim3.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status LIKE 'wc-$status'
        AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_qty'
        AND woim1.meta_key LIKE 'pa_colors'
        AND woim1.meta_value LIKE '$colors'
        AND woim2.meta_key LIKE 'pa_sizes'
        AND woim2.meta_value LIKE '$sizes'
        AND woim3.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
        AND woim3.meta_value = $product_id
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE *examples*:**

- For "Processing" Orders status: `get_ordered_product_count(47652, 'black', 'xs');`
- For specific Orders status: `get_ordered_product_count(47652, 'black', 'xs', 'completed');`

Comment: Loic you came through as always! I had to make a couple of changes: added `function` at beginning, and there is a closed bracket in the first line.

Comment: @RiotAct Oh yes of course… I have just forget that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To count all (published) products with a specific attribute eq with a color 'blue' or 'black' you can use:

```
$colors = 'black, blue';  
$args = array( 
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'meta_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_visibility',
                    'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                    'compare'       => 'IN'
                )
            ),
            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'pa_color',
                    'terms'         => explode(",",$colors),
                    'field'         => 'slug',
                    'operator'      => 'IN'
                )                   
            )
        );

echo count (wc_get_products($args));
```

Comment: Yes but this is not getting the ordered products, just products in general.